# Simple word problem - create equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I need help forming the equations, I don't want the answer, I just want assistance in finding the answer.

Variables have already been declared as the following

C = Cost

b = number of loaves baked

R = Revenue

[image]

EDIT: I thought the first equation should be C = 0.60b But that seems to be incorrect.

Comment: You forgot about the fixed cost of $80$ bucks just to rent the place even if you don't bake any bread.

Comment: So that means it should be C = 0.60b + 80, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: You are welcome. The leaving out of the $80$ was a minor oversight. In setting up equations, we need to think concretely (how much doe we spend) *before* turning to algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edit you say that your firsts attempt to find the equation for the first question is $C = 0.60b$ here, you're thinking in the correct way but your forgetting to add the cost that doesn't depend on $b$

You should be fine with the second question

Comment: Thank, you helped me without giving me the answer completely, just what I wanted!!

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at the sentences at (a) and try to explain $C=0.6b +80$. Similar for (b) $R=1.6b$. Can you write down a formula for the profit? How many loaves have to be sold to make it a profitable business?